# Pyopengl - several lines drawn from VBO however indexed colour VBO doesn't work

Tags: python, opengl, colors, vbo, pyopengl

So I have successfully drawn a series of lines using a two VBOs one for the vertices and one for the indexes. The Python lists are:

```
vertices = [
            [0,1],[0,2],[0,3], # Axes 1
            [1,4],[1,5],[1,6], # Axes 2
            [2,10],[2,11],[2,12] # Axes 3
           ]

indexes = [
           0,4,4,7, # Line 1
           1,4,4,8, # Line 2
           3,6,6,9 # Line 3
          ]
```

I then convert these to a numpy array and aso to VBOs:

```
 vertexarray = np.array(vertices, dtype=np.float32)
 indexarray = np.array(indexes, dtype=np.int32)

 vertexvbo = glvbo.VBO(vertexarray)
 indexvbo = glvbo.VBO(indexarray, target=GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER)
```

And then I bind and draw these lines using:

```
glLineWidth(1)
glColor4f(1,1,1,1)   

glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
glEnable(GL_BLEND)

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
vertexvbo.bind()
indexvbo.bind()
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)

glDrawElements(GL_LINES, len(indexarray), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glDisable(GL_BLEND)
```

As this picture shows (the bold white lines are just axes that are drawn using standard OpenGL commands):

[image: Uncolored Lines]

Now the problem comes when I try and colour these. As each of the 3 lines is made up of 2 smaller lines, I create a color array of size 3:

```
colors = []

for i in range(0,3):
        r = random.uniform(0.1,1)
        g = random.uniform(0.1,1)
        b = random.uniform(0.1,1)
        color = [r,g,b,0.7]
        colors.append(color)
```

And then a color index array with the following values:

```
colorindexes = [
                0,0,0,0, # Line 1
                1,1,1,1, # Line 2
                2,2,2,2 # Line 3
               ]
```

I then convert these to numpy arrays and create VBOs:

```
colorarray = np.array(colors, dtype=np.float32)
colorindexarray = np.array(colorindexes, dtype=np.int32)

colorvbo = glvbo.VBO(colorarray)
colorindexvbo = glvbo.VBO(colorindexarray, target=GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER)
```

In order to then bind and use this VBO I add the following code before the glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY) line from the previous code:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
colorvbo.bind()
colorindexvbo.bind()
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
```

However the lines don't color properly, as the following picture shows, (the data for the lines is random so these lines aren't supposed to intersect at the same points as in the previous picture):

[image: Colored Lines]

Comment: I am thoroughly confused by your use of the word "colour index" here. In some places your code seems to use them in the [proper sense](http://web.agelid.com/protect/utile/documentation/OpenGL/OpenGL%204%20-%20Color%20Index%20Mode.htm) (e.g. the alternative color mode to RGB[A]) but in other places you are using them as an element array buffer (e.g. indices for drawing vertices). Can you elaborate exactly what you are trying to do here? Color indices would be setup using a call to `glIndexPointer (...)`, but I am not convinced you are actually using the term "colour index" properly.

Comment: I mean an index to the list of colour tuples. Where each two segment line has a different colour and therefore different colour index values. Basically I am trying to find a method whereby I can colour each of the lines separately when drawn from the VBO of vertices. Bear in mind in my full code I draw millions of lines...

Comment: Also why can't I use the `glColorPointer(...)` function [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glColorPointer.xml), I used this before when I was drawing the lines from an unindexed VBO?

Comment: You can use `glColorPointer (...)`. What I menat in my previous comment was that for ***indexed*** colors (e.g. **34** instead of RGB (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)) you use `glIndexPointer (...)`. The color pointer is for RGB[A] colors and index pointer is for index colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a heads up, [***"indexed colour"***](http://web.agelid.com/protect/utile/documentation/OpenGL/OpenGL%204%20-%20Color%20Index%20Mode.htm) actually has a completely different meaning from what you are implying here. At first, I thought you were actually using indexed colors instead of **RGB**[*A*]. What you are doing here is drawing vertices (with color) using an element array buffer, which you refer to as indices. It may sound pedantic, especially since almost nobody uses index color modes these days, but it definitely caught me off guard initially.

As for the actual question, I have spent some time looking over your code and I think you are under the impression that OpenGL uses a separate element buffer to index each type of vertex attribute.

This is not the case, while you can use multiple VBOs to store each vertex attribute, they function as if they were one single array of structured data. That is, you cannot do something like select vertex position **#0**, vertex color **#4** and vertex normal **#2** by using separate element arrays. You have a single element array and it always pulls each vertex attribute from the same index.

Unfortunately, the behavior discussed above means that when you have vertices that share some, but not all, attributes you wind up having to make two discrete vertices. More importantly, it means that your color array should have the same length as your position array and you only use a single index array to draw using both.

Comment: Okay I was hoping this wouldn't be the case. I was aware that the vertex structure can store colour and normals etc, but obviously as you said this wouldn't work in my case where a line is made up of several smaller lines. Also thanks for the clarification about "indexed colours".

Comment: Also I understand this is going outside of the scope of the original question but is there a way I can modify my VBO such that I can draw the complete line (i.e. 2 segments) in one 'call' (using this term loosely here because obviously i'm using VBOs) and thus I can store less colours and indices and therefore reduce the data transfer to the GPU?

Comment: @JamesElder: I am not entirely sure what you mean. When GL draws primitives (i.e. lines) it is not required to transfer a new set of vertices or fetch and re-compute each vertex. Particularly when you use an indexed drawing command or a fan or strip primitive. It will re-use vertices when either of those two things happen, which is important for things like vertex shading because it reduces the transform workload. You are using an indexed drawing command here, so (provided a good set of indices) vertices are re-used and you are using the GPU memory about as efficiently as you could hope for.

Comment: @JamesElder: In fact, I think what you may have been getting at is known as a [line strip](http://glasnost.itcarlow.ie/~powerk/technology/opengl/primitives/primitives.jpeg). You can reduce the number of indices necessary if you draw your lines in such a way that they are in strip-order. The big problem, however, is that every line will be connected if you do this... you wind up having to insert a special index to tell GL to break the strip apart (primitive restart index, in GL 3.1+).

Comment: Yes I was getting at a line strip, thank you! Although I can't use primitive restart as it doesn't appear to be supported under PyopenGL for Mac OSX. Looks like I can't reduce the data transfer any further than it is currently then...

Comment: I have a problem in doing it via the method mentioned in that as some lines share vertices from the vertex array, they have the same index value. This therefore means that when the colour array is indexed using the index array two lines sharing a vertex then share the colour also...